# batch scripting: help writing if statments

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I am having issues with IF statements when an option isn't selected.
Problem occurs on line 57-71 and again 115-124 i want to know how to put an option to make it to return and cls to the last option. for example if it is an incorrect username it needs to cls and go back to the input username same for password and on the main menu to cls and return if an option wasn't typed.

My code is :

```
@echo off

:top
cls
title Greg's Batch
call :ColorText 0c "Welcome "
set /p ".= " <nul
call :ColorText 0a " to"
set /p ".= " <nul
call :ColorText 0f " Greg's Batch File"
set /p ".= " <nul
echo. <nul
echo   Time: %time%       Date: %date%       Username: %username%
echo   Loaded From:   %cd%
echo.
echo.

:login
call :ColorText 0c " Username"
echo. <nul
SET /P loginname=
:L5
call :ColorText 0c " Password"
echo. <nul
   :HInput
   SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
   Set "password="
   Rem Save 0x08 character in BS variable
   For /F %%# In (
   '"Prompt;$H&For %%# in (1) Do Rem"'
   ) Do Set "BS=%%#"

   :HILoop
   Set "Key="
   For /F "delims=" %%# In (
   'Xcopy /L /W "%~f0" "%~f0" 2^>Nul'
   ) Do If Not Defined Key Set "Key=%%#"
   Set "Key=%Key:~-1%"
   SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   If Not Defined Key Goto :HIEnd
   If %BS%==^%Key% (Set /P "=%BS% %BS%" <Nul
   Set "Key="
   If Defined password Set "password=!password:~0,-1!"
   ) Else Set /P "=*" <Nul
   If Not Defined password (EndLocal &Set "password=%Key%"
   ) Else For /F delims^=^ eol^= %%# In (
   "!password!") Do EndLocal &Set "password=%%#%Key%"
   Goto :HILoop

   :HIEnd <nul
   Echo( <nul
Echo Your password is '!password!' <nul
   Pause <nul
   Goto :pass

:pass
if loginname==gbattis (
        goto :password1
    ) else (
        cls
        goto :login
    )

:password1
if password==password  (
        goto :logindone
    ) else (
        cls
        goto :L5
    )

:: :::::::Login Done:::::::
:logindone
:menua
cls
echo. 
echo. 
call :ColorText 0f "                               Main Menu"
echo. 
echo. 
color 0f
echo   Time: %time%       Date: %date%       Username: %username%
echo   Loaded From:   %cd%
call :ColorText 0F "Select an option"
echo.
echo.
echo.
call :ColorText 0a "     input option = program"
echo.
echo. 
call :ColorText 0a "     taskman = task list"
echo.
echo.
call :ColorText 0a "     exp = explorer"
echo.
echo.
call :ColorText 0a "     games = game pack"
echo.
echo.
call :ColorText 0a "     sys = System Info"
echo.
echo.
call :ColorText 0a "     IP = Ipconfig"
echo.
echo.
call :ColorText 0a "     timer = Timer"
echo.
echo.
call :ColorText 0a "     md = Make Directory"
echo.
echo.
call :ColorText 0a "     google = search google"
echo.
echo.
SET /P %mainmenuoption%= Option:
if %mainmenuoption%==taskman goto :taskman
if %mainmenuoption%==exp start :explorer
if %mainmenuoption%==sys goto :sys
if %mainmenuoption%==timer goto :timer
if %mainmenuoption%==game goto :gamepack
if %mainmenuoption%==ip goto :ipconfig
if %mainmenuoption%==md goto :makedir
if %mainmenuoption%==google goto :google
if %mainmenuoption%==* goto :menua

:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:google
set string=%string: =+%
set /p SC=
start http://www.google.com/search?q=%SC%
goto :menua

:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:makedir
cls
SET /P dirl= Directory Location (type quit to go back):
if %dirl%==quit goto :menua
md %dirl%
echo Done!
pause
goto :menua

:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:ipconfig
color 0a
ipconfig /all
pause
goto :menua

:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:timer
cls
call :ColorText 0a "                                Timer"
echo.
SET /P seconds= Time in seconds to count down:
pause <nul
color 0f
cls
echo.
echo Press any key to begin timer
pause <nul
cls
TIMEOUT /t %seconds%
echo.
cls
echo.
call :ColorText 0a "  Time is up. "
pause
goto :menua

:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:sys
cls
call sys.bat
pause <nul
goto :logindone

:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:gamepack
call Start.bat
goto :maina

:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:taskman
REM Quelle www.source-center.de
Title Process Manager
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
PUSHD "%TEMP%"
set SPW=0
set offset=
set sorder=
set osetpid=27
set osetmem=60
set osetcpu=141

:Reload
cls
set num=0
echo -----------------------------------------------
echo [Process Name]      [PID]       [MEM] [CPUTime]
echo -----------------------------------------------
if not defined NAME set NAME=All
if "!NAME!" == "All" (
tasklist /FO TABLE /NH /V | SORT !offset! !sorder! >"plist.txt"
) else (
tasklist /FI "USERNAME eq !NAME!" /FO TABLE /NH /V | SORT !offset! !sorder! >"plist.txt"
)
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (plist.txt) do (
set /a num+=1
set tempvar=%%a
if "!tempvar:~34,1!" == " " (
set "list=!tempvar:~0,20! !tempvar:~29,5! !tempvar:~66,9!K!tempvar:~147,10!"
set osetpid=29
set osetmem=66
set osetcpu=147
) else (
set "list=!tempvar:~0,20! !tempvar:~27,5! !tempvar:~60,9!K!tempvar:~141,10!"
set osetpid=27
set osetmem=60
set osetcpu=141
)
echo !list!
)
:Reload_End
del /F "plist.txt" >nul 2>&1
echo.
echo ----------------------------------------------
if "!NAME!"=="All" (
echo All processes - [!num!] Processes running
) else (
echo !NAME! - [!num!] Processes running
)
echo ----------------------------------------------
echo.
if not defined ac (
if /i "!NAME!"=="%username%" goto :MNG
if /i "!NAME!"=="SYSTEM" goto :MNG
if /i "!NAME!"=="All" goto :MNG
)
if /i "!ac!"=="A" set NAME=
if /i "!ac!"=="U" set NAME=%username%
if /i "!ac!"=="S" set NAME=SYSTEM
if /i "!ac!"=="T" goto :SPW
if /i "!ac!"=="E" goto :Explore
if /i "!ac!"=="K" goto :Kill
if /i "!ac!"=="M" goto :SMEM
if /i "!ac!"=="N" goto :SNAME
if /i "!ac!"=="P" goto :SPID
if /i "!ac!"=="X" EXIT
if /i "!ac!"=="1a" goto :logindone
if /i "!ac!"=="1A" goto :logindone
set ac=
goto :Reload


:MNG
echo Options:
echo  Sort by:    N=Name, P=PID,     M=MEM
echo  Show procs: A=All,  S=System,  U=User, T=Paths
echo  Functions:  K=Kill, E=Explore, X=Exit
echo  1a=Main Menu
set /p ac=Manage : 
if "!SPW!" == "1" goto :EOF
goto :Reload

:SPW
set SPW=1
cls
wmic process get ExecutablePath,ProcessID
echo.
call :MNG
if /i "!ac!"=="E" set SPW=0&&goto :Explore
if /i "!ac!"=="K" set SPW=0&&goto :Kill
set SPW=0
goto :Reload


:Kill
echo Type PID to Kill.
set /p PID=PID: 
if not defined PID (
set ac=
goto :Reload
)
taskkill /F /PID !PID! >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 (echo No task running with this PID.) else (
if !PID! geq 0 if !PID! lss 10 (
echo Cannot kill a critical process.
goto :clr_var
) else (
echo Success: Task with PID=!PID!
echo          has been terminated.
))
:clr_var
set ac=
set PID=
set exepath=
del /F "path.txt" >nul 2>&1
pause >nul
goto :Reload

:Explore
echo Type PID to explore.
set /p PID=PID: 
if not defined PID (
set ac=
goto :Reload
)
if !PID! lss 10 goto :clr_var
if !PID! gtr 10000 goto :clr_var
wmic process get ProcessID,ExecutablePath | find " !PID!" >"path.txt"
for /f "delims=" %%a in (path.txt) do (
set tempvar=%%a
for /f "delims=" %%b in ("!tempvar!") do set exepath=%%~dpb
)
if not defined exepath (
echo No task running with this PID.
pause >nul
) else (
explorer ""!exepath!""
)
goto :clr_var

:SNAME
set offset=
set sorder=
set ac=
goto :Reload

:SPID
set offset=/+!osetpid!
set sorder=
set ac=
goto :Reload

:1a
cls
goto :maina

:SMEM
set offset=/+!osetmem!
set sorder=/R
set ac=
goto :reload

:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:ColorText [%1 = Color] [%2 = Text]
set /p ".=." > "%~2" <nul 
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul 2>nul
set /p ".=" <nul
if "%3" == "end" set /p ".=  " <nul
del "%~2" >nul 2>nul
:last
exit /b
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code in here and describe the problem in more detail. What do you want to achieve and how is the current implementation different from that?

Comment: I need the user name and password to work and if no option is specified i want it to ask the user again for the information and the main menu (:menua tag) needs to function the same also. If no option is specified it needs to cls and re ask for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem and here is you code patched.

The first `if`statement you forgot to put `%` on either side of the variables:

```
:pass
:: loginname should be %loginname%
if loginname==gbattis ( 
        goto :password1
    ) else (
        cls
        goto :login
    )

:password1
:: password should be %password%
if password==password  (
        goto :logindone
    ) else (
        cls
        goto :L5
    )
```

For the first and the second `if`statements you did not put quotation marks around the variables, which means if they are blank they will cause your program to crash. Always quote `if`statements like so:

```
if "%variablename%"=="VALUE"
```

Here is your code patched up.

### Code

```
@echo off

:top
cls
title Greg's Batch
call :ColorText 0c "Welcome "
set /p ".= " <nul
call :ColorText 0a " to"
set /p ".= " <nul
call :ColorText 0f " Greg's Batch File"
set /p ".= " <nul
echo. <nul
echo   Time: %time%       Date: %date%       Username: %username%
echo   Loaded From:   %cd%
echo.
echo.

:login
call :ColorText 0c " Username"
echo. <nul
SET /P loginname=
:L5
call :ColorText 0c " Password"
echo. <nul
   :HInput
   SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
   Set "password="
   Rem Save 0x08 character in BS variable
   For /F %%# In (
   '"Prompt;$H&For %%# in (1) Do Rem"'
   ) Do Set "BS=%%#"

   :HILoop
   Set "Key="
   For /F "delims=" %%# In (
   'Xcopy /L /W "%~f0" "%~f0" 2^>Nul'
   ) Do If Not Defined Key Set "Key=%%#"
   Set "Key=%Key:~-1%"
   SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   If Not Defined Key Goto :HIEnd
   If %BS%==^%Key% (Set /P "=%BS% %BS%" <Nul
   Set "Key="
   If Defined password Set "password=!password:~0,-1!"
   ) Else Set /P "=*" <Nul
   If Not Defined password (EndLocal &Set "password=%Key%"
   ) Else For /F delims^=^ eol^= %%# In (
   "!password!") Do EndLocal &Set "password=%%#%Key%"
   Goto :HILoop

   :HIEnd <nul
   Echo( <nul
Echo Your password is '!password!' <nul
   Pause <nul
   Goto :pass

:pass
if "%loginname%"=="gbattis" (
        goto :password1
    ) else (
        cls
        goto :login
    )

:password1
if "%password%"=="password" (
        goto :logindone
    ) else (
        cls
        goto :L5
    )

:: :::::::Login Done:::::::
:logindone
:menua
cls
echo. 
echo. 
call :ColorText 0f "                               Main Menu"
echo. 
echo. 
color 0f
echo   Time: %time%       Date: %date%       Username: %username%
echo   Loaded From:   %cd%
call :ColorText 0F "Select an option"
echo.
echo.
echo.
call :ColorText 0a "     input option = program"
echo.
echo. 
call :ColorText 0a "     taskman = task list"
echo.
echo.
call :ColorText 0a "     exp = explorer"
echo.
echo.
call :ColorText 0a "     games = game pack"
echo.
echo.
call :ColorText 0a "     sys = System Info"
echo.
echo.
call :ColorText 0a "     IP = Ipconfig"
echo.
echo.
call :ColorText 0a "     timer = Timer"
echo.
echo.
call :ColorText 0a "     md = Make Directory"
echo.
echo.
call :ColorText 0a "     google = search google"
echo.
echo.
SET /P %mainmenuoption%= Option:
if "%mainmenuoption%"=="taskman" goto :taskman
if "%mainmenuoption%"=="exp" start :explorer
if "%mainmenuoption%"=="sys" goto :sys
if "%mainmenuoption%"=="timer" goto :timer
if "%mainmenuoption%"=="game" goto :gamepack
if "%mainmenuoption%"=="ip" goto :ipconfig
if "%mainmenuoption%"=="md" goto :makedir
if "%mainmenuoption%"=="google" goto :google
if "%mainmenuoption%"=="*" goto :menua

:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:google
set string=%string: =+%
set /p SC=
start http://www.google.com/search?q=%SC%
goto :menua

:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:makedir
cls
SET /P dirl= Directory Location (type quit to go back):
if %dirl%==quit goto :menua
md %dirl%
echo Done!
pause
goto :menua

:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:ipconfig
color 0a
ipconfig /all
pause
goto :menua

:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:timer
cls
call :ColorText 0a "                                Timer"
echo.
SET /P seconds= Time in seconds to count down:
pause <nul
color 0f
cls
echo.
echo Press any key to begin timer
pause <nul
cls
TIMEOUT /t %seconds%
echo.
cls
echo.
call :ColorText 0a "  Time is up. "
pause
goto :menua

:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:sys
cls
call sys.bat
pause <nul
goto :logindone

:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:gamepack
call Start.bat
goto :maina

:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:taskman
REM Quelle www.source-center.de
Title Process Manager
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
PUSHD "%TEMP%"
set SPW=0
set offset=
set sorder=
set osetpid=27
set osetmem=60
set osetcpu=141

:Reload
cls
set num=0
echo -----------------------------------------------
echo [Process Name]      [PID]       [MEM] [CPUTime]
echo -----------------------------------------------
if not defined NAME set NAME=All
if "!NAME!" == "All" (
tasklist /FO TABLE /NH /V | SORT !offset! !sorder! >"plist.txt"
) else (
tasklist /FI "USERNAME eq !NAME!" /FO TABLE /NH /V | SORT !offset! !sorder! >"plist.txt"
)
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (plist.txt) do (
set /a num+=1
set tempvar=%%a
if "!tempvar:~34,1!" == " " (
set "list=!tempvar:~0,20! !tempvar:~29,5! !tempvar:~66,9!K!tempvar:~147,10!"
set osetpid=29
set osetmem=66
set osetcpu=147
) else (
set "list=!tempvar:~0,20! !tempvar:~27,5! !tempvar:~60,9!K!tempvar:~141,10!"
set osetpid=27
set osetmem=60
set osetcpu=141
)
echo !list!
)
:Reload_End
del /F "plist.txt" >nul 2>&1
echo.
echo ----------------------------------------------
if "!NAME!"=="All" (
echo All processes - [!num!] Processes running
) else (
echo !NAME! - [!num!] Processes running
)
echo ----------------------------------------------
echo.
if not defined ac (
if /i "!NAME!"=="%username%" goto :MNG
if /i "!NAME!"=="SYSTEM" goto :MNG
if /i "!NAME!"=="All" goto :MNG
)
if /i "!ac!"=="A" set NAME=
if /i "!ac!"=="U" set NAME=%username%
if /i "!ac!"=="S" set NAME=SYSTEM
if /i "!ac!"=="T" goto :SPW
if /i "!ac!"=="E" goto :Explore
if /i "!ac!"=="K" goto :Kill
if /i "!ac!"=="M" goto :SMEM
if /i "!ac!"=="N" goto :SNAME
if /i "!ac!"=="P" goto :SPID
if /i "!ac!"=="X" EXIT
if /i "!ac!"=="1a" goto :logindone
if /i "!ac!"=="1A" goto :logindone
set ac=
goto :Reload


:MNG
echo Options:
echo  Sort by:    N=Name, P=PID,     M=MEM
echo  Show procs: A=All,  S=System,  U=User, T=Paths
echo  Functions:  K=Kill, E=Explore, X=Exit
echo  1a=Main Menu
set /p ac=Manage : 
if "!SPW!" == "1" goto :EOF
goto :Reload

:SPW
set SPW=1
cls
wmic process get ExecutablePath,ProcessID
echo.
call :MNG
if /i "!ac!"=="E" set SPW=0&&goto :Explore
if /i "!ac!"=="K" set SPW=0&&goto :Kill
set SPW=0
goto :Reload


:Kill
echo Type PID to Kill.
set /p PID=PID: 
if not defined PID (
set ac=
goto :Reload
)
taskkill /F /PID !PID! >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 (echo No task running with this PID.) else (
if !PID! geq 0 if !PID! lss 10 (
echo Cannot kill a critical process.
goto :clr_var
) else (
echo Success: Task with PID=!PID!
echo          has been terminated.
))
:clr_var
set ac=
set PID=
set exepath=
del /F "path.txt" >nul 2>&1
pause >nul
goto :Reload

:Explore
echo Type PID to explore.
set /p PID=PID: 
if not defined PID (
set ac=
goto :Reload
)
if !PID! lss 10 goto :clr_var
if !PID! gtr 10000 goto :clr_var
wmic process get ProcessID,ExecutablePath | find " !PID!" >"path.txt"
for /f "delims=" %%a in (path.txt) do (
set tempvar=%%a
for /f "delims=" %%b in ("!tempvar!") do set exepath=%%~dpb
)
if not defined exepath (
echo No task running with this PID.
pause >nul
) else (
explorer ""!exepath!""
)
goto :clr_var

:SNAME
set offset=
set sorder=
set ac=
goto :Reload

:SPID
set offset=/+!osetpid!
set sorder=
set ac=
goto :Reload

:1a
cls
goto :maina

:SMEM
set offset=/+!osetmem!
set sorder=/R
set ac=
goto :reload

:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:ColorText [%1 = Color] [%2 = Text]
set /p ".=." > "%~2" <nul 
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul 2>nul
set /p ".=" <nul
if "%3" == "end" set /p ".=  " <nul
del "%~2" >nul 2>nul
:last
exit /b
```